# PHP session gets destroyed

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, redirect

My website was under a folder /test/ for example, and everything was working great. I was using relative urls and after I moved the site to the root folder, everything got double slashes.

For example: `test.com//` etc and I fixed it through htaccess url rewrite, but when I login, my site is getting redirected to the homepage where I can see the user menu which means the session exists. But when I click on settings and navigate to the settings edit page, I automatically get redirected to login page for the reason that there is no session exists.

Everything was working great before site move to root folder, so nothing wrong with coding I think, any ideas what it can be?

**config.php**

```
<?php
    $username = "***";
    $password = "***";
    $host = "***";
    $dbname = "***";

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

    try
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array)
        {
            foreach($array as &$value)
            {
                if(is_array($value))
                {
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value);
                }
                else
                {
                    $value = stripslashes($value);
                }
            }
        }

        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST);
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET);
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE);
    }

    session_start();
```

**Top of edit.php**

```
require("config.php");
require('includes/top.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: /login.php");
    die("Redirecting to login.php");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see some code where the session is being created?

Comment: I have a config.php which is included at the top of every page which includes the mysql connection and at the end of it it has session_start();

Comment: 99% of the time, `session_start();` needs to be at the top, and not at the end, as you say. @ArtemisChaitidis Without seeing code, it's like shooting golf balls at night.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so here is the top code of edit.php:

 require("config.php");
 require('includes/top.php');
 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
       header("Location: /login.php");
        die("Redirecting to login.php");
    }

and the code of the config.php:

http://pastebin.com/shVKPR14

Comment: All I can tell, is that you're not assigning a session variable, only checking if it's not set. So of course it will fail. Depending on how your login page is setup, if it doesn't contain something to the effect of `$_SESSION['user']=$_POST['user'];` as an example if taken from a POST variable and a named form element `<input type="text" name="user">`, then yeah... it's going to fail. @ArtemisChaitidis

Comment: @Fred-ii- on my login.php after I check if the login is current I use this line: $_SESSION['user'] = $row; so ye I do create a session.